# Disallow * in php Search

Tags: php

I want to suppress Searches on a database from users inputting (for example) P*.

http://www.aircrewremembered.com/DeutscheKreuzGoldDatabase/

I can't work out how to add this to the code I already have. I'm guessing using an array in the line `$trimmed = str_replace("\"","'",trim($search));` is the answer, replacing the `"\""` with the `array`, but I can't seem to find the correct way of doing this. I can get it to work if I just replace the `\` with `*`, but then I lose the trimming of the `"\"` character: does this matter?

```
// Retrieve query variable and pass through regular expression.
// Test for unacceptable characters such as quotes, percent signs, etc.
// Trim out whitespace.  If ereg expression not passed, produce warning.
$search = @$_GET['q'];
// check if wrapped in quotes
if ( preg_match( '/^(["\']).*\1$/m', $search ) === 1 ) {
   $boolean = FALSE;
}

if ( escape_data($search) ) {
   //trim whitespace and additional disallowed characters from the stored variable
   $trimmed = str_replace("\"","'",trim($search));
   $trimmed = stripslashes(str_ireplace("'","", $trimmed));
   $prehighlight = stripslashes($trimmed);
   $prehighlight = str_ireplace("\"", "", $prehighlight);
   $append = stripslashes(urlencode($trimmed));
} else {
   $trimmed = "";
   $testquery = FALSE;
}

$display = stripslashes($trimmed);
```

Comment: for starters, what is `escape_data` doing?

Comment: Ah! I have no idea! This is a script I bought because my own crashed all the time! I am hoping this script protects us from SQL injection attacks, and that's what I thought escape_data was doing. Am I wrong? If so, HELP!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You already said it yourself, just use arrays as parameters for str_repace:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php

```
$trimmed = str_replace( array("\"", "*"), array("'", ""), trim($search) );
```

Every element in the first array will be replaced with the cioresponding element from the second array.

---

For future validation and sanitation, you might want to read about this function too:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php

Comment: Brilliant. Thanks. I must have a blind spot because I just couldn't figure out the replace needed an array also. I just had the array defined for the items I wanted to replace

Comment: Yea, I would hope str_replace would accept a single item as second parameter and just replace eveerything with that, but it doesnt. :(

Answer (score 0):

use `$search=mysql_real_escape_string($search);` it will remove all characters from `$search` which can affect your query.

Comment: Welcome. happyCoding :D